# In a Xamarin MVVM application, how can I change what I see on the screen from the ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application viewModel responds to a user clicking a button to see test results:

```
    private void AddDetailRows(List<QuizHistory> quizHistoryList)
    {
        quizDetails.Children.Clear();
        quizDetails.Children.Add(AddData(quizHistoryList));
        quizDetails.Children.Add(new LineTemplate());
    }
```

Where quizDetails is the name of an element in the view.

But this doesn't work for me as the view model doesn't know what the view looks like and does not have access to the names of elements.

In a MVVM application, how is this problem solved?

Comment: I think similler things has discussed in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246715/accessing-view-from-viewmodel

Comment: What kind of elements are you trying to add? And what kind of element is quizDetails?

Comment: You can create a Custom Control of the element and make the necessary changes in it, similar to how ListView works... as @iSpain17 has mentioned, provide more details about what type of element you are trying to clear and add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are completely right, that is not something that ViewModel is responsible of.
So, whatever you want to do with UI is not responsibility of the ViewModel.
If this is really the only option, then you can think of creating boolean properties in your VM and binding them to your views and then changing that boolean from false to true or vice versa on button click command which is binded to your VM.
To simplify it:

MyView.xaml

```
<StackLayout>
   <Button Command="{Binding ShowHideQuizHistoryCommand}" ... />
   <StackLayout x:Name="QuizHistory"
                IsVisible={Binding ShowQuizHistory }>
       //
   </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
private bool _showQuizHistory ;

public bool ShowQuizHistory 
{
    get { return _showQuizHistory ; }
    set
    {
        _showQuizHistory = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}


public ICommand ShowHideQuizHistoryCommand => new Command(() =>
{
    ShowQuizHistory = !ShowQuizHistory;
});
```

So, this is just an example based on what you provided in question.
You can also use visual states, converters, triggers and behaviors in order to achieve this, but in my opinion this is the easiest way.